# ! LaTeX Error: Environment Verbatim undefined in Texlive in Linux Mint

Tags: errors, texlive, verbatim, minted, linux

I'm using Texmaker with Texlive in Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon to write an article with some Python code. Then I got a problem: `! LaTeX Error: Environment Verbatim undefined in Texlive in Linux Mint`

The problem is, my code work well on a Window 10 computer with MikTex and Texmaker, and it also produces no error on Overleaf.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{minted}
\newmintinline[pycode]{python}{}
%\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\pycode{pow()} is a function in Python
\end{document}
```

Here is the error on my computer.

[image]

And here is the result on Overleaf:

[image]

Here is the log file on my computer

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.1.20)  20 JAN 2024 16:42
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**testcode.tex
(./testcode.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tex-gyre/tgpagella.sty
Package: tgpagella 2009/09/27 v1.2 TeX Gyre Pagella as default roman family

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)))
(./minted.sty
Package: minted 2023/12/18 v2.9 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
Package: fvextra 2019/02/04 v1.4 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count193
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2021/12/21 4.1b verbatim text (tvz,hv)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count194
\FV@InFile=\read2
\FV@TabBox=\box50
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count195
\FV@StepNumber=\count196
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count197
\output=\toks17
\linenoprevgraf=\count198
\linenumbersep=\dimen139
\linenumberwidth=\dimen140
\c@linenumber=\count199
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count266
\c@LN@truepage=\count267
\c@internallinenumber=\count268
\c@internallinenumbers=\count269
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen141
\bframerule=\dimen142
\bframesep=\dimen143
\bframebox=\box51
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
\c@FV@TrueTabGroupLevel=\count270
\c@FV@TrueTabCounter=\count271
\FV@TabBox@Group=\box52
\FV@TmpLength=\skip49
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStart=\count272
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStop=\count273
\FV@LoopCount=\count274
\FV@NCharsBox=\box53
\FV@BreakIndent=\dimen144
\FV@BreakIndentNChars=\count275
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeft=\dimen145
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeftNChars=\count276
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRight=\dimen146
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRightNChars=\count277
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft=\dimen147
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeftNChars=\count278
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRight=\dimen148
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRightNChars=\count279
\c@FancyVerbLineBreakLast=\count280
\FV@LineBox=\box54
\FV@LineIndentBox=\box55
\FV@LineWidth=\dimen149
)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 33, version
               `2022/11/30' of package fvextra,
               but only version
               `2019/02/04 v1.4 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb'
               is available.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
runsystem(uname -s > "testcode.w18")...executed.

 (./testcode.w18)
runsystem(rm -- "testcode.w18")...executed.

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count281
\decimalpart=\count282
)
Package: xstring 2021/07/21 v1.84 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip50
\fb@frw=\dimen150
\fb@frh=\dimen151
\FrameRule=\dimen152
\FrameSep=\dimen153
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count283
\float@exts=\toks18
\float@box=\box56
\@float@everytoks=\toks19
\@floatcapt=\box57
)
\minted@appexistsfile=\read3
\minted@bgbox=\box58
\minted@code=\write4
\c@minted@FancyVerbLineTemp=\count284
\c@minted@pygmentizecounter=\count285
\@float@every@listing=\toks20
\c@listing=\count286
)
runsystem(mkdir -p _minted-testcode)...executed.


(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
runsystem(command -v pygmentize && touch testcode.aex)...executed.

runsystem(rm testcode.aex)...executed.

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+qpl on input line 5
.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tex-gyre/ot1qpl.fd
File: ot1qpl.fd 2009/09/25 v1.2 font definition file for OT1/qpl
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count287
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box59
)
(./testcode.aux)
\openout1 = `testcode.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count288
\scratchdimen=\dimen154
\scratchbox=\box60
\nofMPsegments=\count289
\nofMParguments=\count290
\everyMPshowfont=\toks21
\MPscratchCnt=\count291
\MPscratchDim=\dimen155
\MPnumerator=\count292
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count293
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks22
)
\openout4 = `testcode.pyg'.

 (./_minted-testcode/default.pygstyle)
(./_minted-testcode/ECBEE7850F6F42A3EE42B2DD166E759B7123E940C453CDFD3D7E37FB6AC
B949A.pygtex

! LaTeX Error: Environment Verbatim undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \begin{Verbatim}
                    [commandchars=\\\{\}]
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+qpl on input line 1
.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file OMSqpl.fd. on input line 1.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/qpl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbraceleft' on input line 1.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{Verbatim}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \end{Verbatim}
                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

) [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./testcode.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

runsystem(rm testcode.pyg)...executed.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5262 strings out of 479598
 101401 string characters out of 5881832
 430206 words of memory out of 5000000
 23330 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 472755 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 331 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 74i,5n,77p,286b,256s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/tex-gyre/q-rm.enc}</usr/share/texlive/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/p
ublic/tex-gyre/qplr.pfb>
Output written on testcode.pdf (1 page, 60151 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 19 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 11 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I checked that the Tex live version is 2021.20220204-1, and `minted` package has been installed.

It seem that the latex system here is somehow out of date. The `ignorelexererrors` option in `minted` also leads to an error, and I have to fix it by manually put minted.sty in my folder. However, that doesn't solve my problem above.

So what is the problem and how can I fix that?

Comment: if minted isn't being found it was not correctly installed (you may have two tex systems) and the error is because fancyverb is not being found did you not get an earlier error about that?

Comment: Please, show the full log file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : no, minted is installed, I can check it in Synaptics Package Manager. However, if I include the option `ignorelexererrors=true` it would return `! Package keyval Error: ignorelexererrors undefined.` Now if I manually download and put `minted.sty` in the folder then this problem is solved, but the `verbatim` problem remains the same. I don't have two tex system, I installed tex live via Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: @egreg I've updated my question with the log file.

Comment: you have manually installed a newer minted which as your log now shows is incompatible with the `2019/02/04 v1.4 fvextra that you have. Use the matching minted that came with your system

Comment: @DavidCarlisle verbatim problem had came before I manually installed the minted package. Should I remove all the Tex Live by Synaptic PM and installed it as guided on tug.org/texlive?

Comment: that would be an over-reaction I think. You have broken your system with that manual install but I don't see any evidence to see why your original system texlive should be broken

Comment: or just carry on and manually add fvextra and fancyverb as well